# How to properly do ip specific routing on sbc gateway/router? Not forwarding responce

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, router, gateway

My network uses 192.168.100.0/24

The routers gateway is 192.168.100.1

I have a windows pc at 192.168.100.15

I have a fresh install of ubuntu 20.04 on a SBC with ip 192.168.100.207 lan0

On this sbc I configured a vpn client on 192.168.1.0/24 vpn_mom

DHCP has assigned ip 192.168.1.166 to the vpn adapter

I am able to ping other machines on that remote subnet without issue including 192.168.1.1

I also set up a route for chris.com (34.174.225.83) as follows:

```
ip route add 34.174.225.83 via 192.168.1.1 dev vpn_mom
```

Making route look like :

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 lan0
83.225.174.34.b 192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 vpn_mom
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 lan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vpn_mom
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 lan0
```

If I do a traceroute to chris.com from the sbc it works exactly as I want with out and in bound traffic from the vpn network while all other internet traffic continues working from lan0 as expected.

Then I set up forwarding with this command :

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Then I change the gateway on the windows machine to 192.168.100.207 (sbc)
Testing on the windows machines shows all internet traffic working fine except chris.com

Examining tcpdump show the requests being sent though the vpn on the sbc but the response is not being sent back to the windows machine (192.168.100.15)

I have been searching the internet for a couple of weeks with out any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a NAT on the VPN interface, the issue could be the destination serve/ the network from the other VPN side is not ware of the 192.168.100.0/24 try adding a nat on the VPN Interface.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.100.0/24 -o vpn_mom -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: This seems to have done the trick. I did not have to do anything on the VPN server even though I did try adding a route first.  I removed the route from the server and tried the iptables command and BOOM in business.  Thank you.

Comment: You should probably read the answers together; masquerade (or NAT as it's commonly known) translates addresses, so all traffic appears to be coming from the masquerading host. The consequence of this is that all traffic will appear to be from that host, and no connections in opposite direction is possible. When you control both sides of the network, it's *usually* better to do normal routing.

Comment: the are multiple ways to fix this issue NAT, add from the other side the net 192.168.100.0/24, use a dynamic routing instead of static. I advised the easy one from my perspective

Comment: VPN server is running windows 7 so I tried to add the route before the NAT config with: route ADD 192.168.100.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.166  Did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The remote end needs a route for how to reach `192.168.100.0/24`.

That route will be *via* the VPN server. Remember that routing works both ways, and need not be symmetrical; a packet is a discrete unit, and a reply does not need to follow the same hops as the previous one.